# Alter Behaviour of a 2-Column Flexbox Responsive Grid

Tags: css, responsive-design, flexbox

A standard 2-column grid is quite easily achievable with a few lines of code:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  max-width: 420px;
}
.element {
  margin: 10px auto;
  background-color: #1990C8;
  max-width: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="element">Element 1</div>
  <div class="element">Element 2</div>
  <div class="element">Element 3</div>
  <div class="element">Element 4</div>
</div>
```

Upon resizing the viewport, though, the elements wrap around each other, falling under a single column. That is *perfectly* fine.

What if you wanted the elements to scale down till `@media screen (min-width: value)`, and only *then* allow them to wrap once more leaving the user with a one-column layout? How would *you* achieve this result using purely flexbox and media queries? :)